# Finding a sequence of 4 values in an array without loop

Tags: arrays, matlab

I'm trying to find a sequence of ascending values in an array (4 values) without `for` or `if`.
For example, A = [8 9 1 3 7 18 9], input will be: `1 3 7 18`.

Any way to do it without `for`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the starting indices of all such subsequences:

```
n = 4;
indices = find(conv(double(diff(A)>0), ones(1,n-1), 'valid')==n-1);
```

Example:

```
A = [8 9 1 3 7 18 9 10 11 12 5];
```

produces

```
indices =
     3     7
```

So the subsequences would be `A(indices(1) + (0:n-1))`, `A(indices(2) + (0:n-1))`, etc:

```
>> A(indices(1) + (0:n-1))
ans =
     1     3     7    18

>> A(indices(2) + (0:n-1))
ans =
     9    10    11    12
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution:

```
A = [8 9 1 3 7 18 9 10 11 12 5];
len = 4;

subseqs = hankel(A(1:len), A(len:end));
idx = all(diff(subseqs) > 0);
out = subseqs(:,idx);
```

Answer (score 2):

`strfind` allows you to look for patterns not only in strings, but also numeric arrays. The pattern you're looking for is three consecutive positive differences:

```
A = [8 9 1 3 7 18 19]

sequenceLength = 4;

startIdx = strfind( sign(diff(A)), ones(1,sequenceLength-1));

sequences = A(bsxfun(@plus,startIdx',0:sequenceLength-1))

sequences =

     1     3     7    18
     3     7    18    19
```

Note: `strfind` finds overlapping intervals. If you want exclusive intervals, you may want to look at `regexp`.

Comment: Well seen that `bsxfun` part