# Method for locating sequence matching (Matlab + Chain Code)

Tags: matlab, function

I have a few sequence of chain code, for example:

```
20000600666644644424422220

0670064442422

02005066646424222
```

I want to locate and match a template of chain code, 066664464 in below sequence of chain code. I want it to match partially with either one of them (in this case, it match the first chain code sequence). If it's can locate, mean my template is acceptable.

I try to search what are the name of this method/function, especially to be use in Matlab. For example, the idea of Needleman–Wunsch algorithm which used in bioinformatics to align protein or nucleotide sequences is quite close to what i want to do but with simple numbers, not protein.

Any idea?

Comment: If your sequences are strings, you can use [`strfind`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html)

Comment: @Naveh my sequences are not strings, it's numeric data.

Comment: Turns out it works just as well for numerical data! Check out my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For finding patterns in both numerical arrays and strings, you can use [`strfind`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html). While originally intended for strings, it works perfectly fine on numerical data as well:

```
%// Find a pattern in a string
data = '20000600666644644424422220';
pattern = '066664464';
idx1 = strfind(data, pattern); %// idx1 = 8
%// Find a pattern in numerical data
data = str2num(data')';
pattern = str2num(pattern')';
idx2 = strfind(data, pattern); %// idx2 = 8
```

While using `strfind` for numerical data is not the most efficient method, its ease of use outweighs its inefficiency in many cases (unless your data is very large).

For more information and more effective methods, check out [this enlightening post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/09/08/finding-patterns-in-arrays/) in Loren Shure's blog. And here is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27067046/finding-a-sequence-of-4-values-in-an-array-without-loop) on the site.

Answer (score 1):

As syakey already mentioned, you can most easily just use the `strfind` function

```
if(~isempty(strfind(num2str(chaincode), num2str(template))))
   % // match
else
   % // no match
end
```

Comment: what if it's an array of data?

Comment: Then you should loop through it, at least, if you take this method to compare