# How to Apply Cellfun Vectors with Arrayfun, Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am expanding the `arrayfun` [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36341002/54964) of the thread *To Find Double Sequence With Transforms in Matlab?* for a list of vectors in `cellfun` (`DD`). 
Pseudocode

```
DD = {[9 1 5 6 6 6 5 1 1 0 7 7 7 7 7 8], [1 1 1 4], [7 7 7]};

d = cellfun(@(i) diff(diff([0 i 0]) == 0), DD, 'Uniform', false);
y = cellfun(@(z) ...
    arrayfun(@(i,j) DD{i}(i:j), find(z>0), find(z<0), 'Uniform', false), ...
    d, 'Uniform', false););
```

Expected output

```
y = { {[6 6 6], [1 1], [7 7 7]}, ...
      {[1 1 1]}, ...
      {[7 7 7]} };
```

Error

```
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in findDoubleSequenceAnonFunction>@(i,j)DD{i}(i:j)

Error in
findDoubleSequenceAnonFunction>@(z)arrayfun(@(i,j)DD{i}(i:j),find(z>0),find(z<0),'Uniform',false)

Error in findDoubleSequenceAnonFunction (line 5)
y = cellfun(@(z) ...
```

Comments

- `d = cellfun(...`. I am applying the function `diff(diff(...` in `cellfun`. It should be ok.
- `y = cellfun(...`. Need to have `cellfun` here because have the again a cell of vectors in `d`. Somehow, the cellfun-arrayfun is complicating.

---

How can you have cellfun-arrayfun combination here?

Comment: sometimes it's better to use a for-loop, much more readable.

Comment: Why are you passing three inputs to `arrayfun`? Your anonymous function only expects 2. Seems like your `d` is in the wrong spot

Comment: @Amro When to decide which to use?

Comment: When you can't make sense of your own code

Comment: @Suever Thank you! It was one mistake. I updated the body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a for-loop, easier to read:

```
XX = {[9 1 5 6 6 6 5 1 1 0 7 7 7 7 7 8], [1 1 1 4], [7 7 7]};

YY = cell(size(XX));
for i=1:numel(XX)
    x = XX{i};
    d = diff(diff([0 x 0]) == 0);
    YY{i} = arrayfun(@(i,j) x(i:j), find(d>0), find(d<0), 'Uniform',false);
end
```

Result:

```
>> celldisp(YY)

YY{1}{1} =
     6     6     6
YY{1}{2} =
     1     1
YY{1}{3} =
     7     7     7     7     7

YY{2}{1} =
     1     1     1

YY{3}{1} =
     7     7     7
```